# Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

When trying to install composer in laravel project get this error.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover
>   In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not
>    found
>   Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: sir, I have read problem solution that not working for me. That's why i am asked the question here

Comment: "extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/dusk"
        ]
    }
},
try this in composer.json

I solved the problem this way:

cd bootstrap/cache/
rm -rf *.php

took those two answer from stackoverflow.

Comment: Sir, if it is too easy, then help me, that is save my day

Comment: those two not working for me

Comment: then what is the problem with me :(

Comment: After update composer.json, run composer update locally then deploy on gcp again.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue when deploying my app to Google App Engine. I found that by moving "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0" from "require-dev" to "require" in my composer.json fixed this problem.

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue for days now.  Damn.  Can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Thx. Worked for me, but had to also delete my composer lock and run composer install again.

Answer (score 6):

In your case the problem was that after running `composer install --no-dev`, `php artisan package:discover` is run automatically.

Whenever `php artisan command` fails, it tries to use the class `NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider` for error handling which is only installed when laravel development packages are used. As you can see in  this `composer.json`, collision is in the `require-dev` group.

```json
    "require-dev": {
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
    },
```

The problem can be solved by:

- moving the dependency to the `require` section
- or figuring out what causes the `artisan` command error.

In my case, it was either outdated php files or permission issues in the `bootstrap/cache` directory.

Comment: deleting `bootstrap/cache` fixed the issue: `rm -f bootstrap/cache/*.php`

Comment: Thanks - this answer addresses the root issue rather than just advising changes to composer.json

Answer (score 3):

- move `nunomaduro/collision`: `^2.0` from `require-dev` to `require` in composer

If that doesn't solve the problem, try

- deleting the `composer.lock` file
- uploading the project again without this file (it solved it for me)

Answer (score 2):

I am using 5.6 version with php version 7.2

Tried these page solutions

but following worked for me

in terminal

1. `composer outdated`
2. `composer require nunomaduro/collision:^3.0 --dev`

Note: I have no Idea if the first step is must but I wrote that command in terminal, Try using 2nd only, if it works then suggest me to edit please.

Thank you.

I found this solution from Git Hub page [Github](https://github.com/nunomaduro/collision)

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your **composer.lock** ,

Move `"nunomaduro/larastan": "^0.3.0",` to **"require"** from **"require-dev"** .

then run `composer install`

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was simple:
Delete all files within the bootstrap/cache/ directory.

NOTE: The bootstrap/cache/ directory need to be present, so don't delete it.

Thanks to @8ctopus for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple solution, although not always the correct one:

Delete the cache files (services.php, packages.php, etc) in `<project dir>/bootstrap/cache` directory. Refresh the page and it may be fixed. The problem could be that your packages.php and services.php are out of date, and the application is attempting to load packages/services that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the comments, but this should be the accepted answer as this is what actually solves the problem. the package was already in my 'require' section and not in 'require-dev' yet the error still happened.

**deleting bootstrap/cache fixed the issue: rm -f bootstrap/cache/*.php**

Answer (score -1):

in php v-8 i get this error " Call to undefined method Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryBuilder::create()"
and then in terminall type this "composer outdated" and then i know i should update nunomaduro/collision
then in terminal
"composer require nunomaduro/collision"

Answer (score -2):

I have answer in folder `boostrap/cache/packages.php` , we will succes .So delete package is error.

> Class 'NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\CollisionServiceProvider' not found

Deleting...

So you PHP artisan serve.